# Unknown column '*_._ebean_intercept' in 'field list'

Tags: playframework, ebean

I'm upgraded my play 2.6.7 app to play 2.7.0-R8 and get error "Unknown column '*_._ebean_intercept' in 'field list'" of JPAApi when i try execute following code:

```
jpaApi.withTransaction(entityManager -> {

        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(hql, modelClass);
        return query.getResultList();

    });
```

My dependences:

- sbt-plugin - 2.7.0-RC8
- sbt-play-ebean - 5.0.0-RC2"
- hibernate-core - 5.4.0.Final
- hibernate-entitymanager - 5.4.0.Final

persistence.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
         version="2.1">

<persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to upgrade `Ebean` to latest version